# Dispatch called without explications when button clicked quickly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, cart

*Solution found below*

I am making an add/remove item from cart system.

```
const handleClick = (i) => {
    if (i >= 0 && i <= itemQuantity) {
        console.log("i : " + i);
        setQty(i);
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
if (qty >= 1) {
    dispatch(addToCart(product._id, qty));
} else {
    dispatch(removeFromCart(product._id));
}
}, [qty]);

<button onClick={() => handleClick(qty - 1)}>Substract</button>
<img src={product.image} alt={product.name}    />
<button onClick={() => handleClick(qty + 1)}>Add</button>
```

If I use the buttons slowly, I get a very satysfying result (I cannot substract anymore and Cart is empty) :

[image]

But if I click on the substract button quickly, things go funky, not sure why (I am not trying to go below 0, I exactly click the right number of time to go to qty=0):

[image]

Then I cannot substract more, and quantity gets stuck to 1.

```
export const addToCart = (productId, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { data } = await Axios.get(`/api/prints/${productId}`);
  const {
    cart: { cartItems },
  } = getState();

  dispatch({
    type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
    payload: {
      name: data.name,
      image: data.image,
      price: data.price,
      countInStock: data.countInStock,
      product: data._id,
      seller: data.seller,
      qty,
    },
  });
  localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
};

export const removeFromCart = (productId) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({ type: CART_REMOVE_ITEM, payload: productId });
  localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
};
```

Edit - Solution :

```
      dispatch(addToCart(product._id, qty)).then(() => setLoad(false));
      <button
              disabled={load}
              onClick={() => {
                setLoad(true);
                handleClick(qty - 1);
              }}
            >
```

Comment: you created an infinite loop ! because you added `qty` for `useEffect` and that changes it frequently and executes the effect again again again ...

Comment: Hmm, I do not agree, I clg'ed inside of useEffect and no infinite loop.       dispatch(addToCart(product._id, qty)) is not triggering useEffect. Only setQty(i); is triggering

Comment: Share `addToCart` and `removeFromCart` code

Comment: @GuillaumeAyad Don't use local state for qty (in case you're doing this). Use `useSelector` to get it from the redux store. For add/remove, don't use an effect (it is not an effect after all, it's the result of the user clicking a button. Use `useDispatch` in combination with `useCallback` to create a memoized click handler. Assuming the reducer works correctly, this should resolve all your issues.

Comment: @VitaliyRayets just edited main post.

Timotgl, I'll check what you sugget, thank you

Comment: You have two asyncronous calls `addToCart`  `setQty`. When you call `setQty` response from `addToCart` has not come yet, you must wait it and then call new `setQty`. You can disabled button on click , add loader and then undisabled when response is come.

Comment: @VitaliyRayets Works like a charm thank you :) 
For people interested :
onClick={() => {
                setLoad(true);
                handleClick(qty - 1);
              }}

dispatch(addToCart(product._id, qty)).then(() => setLoad(false));

Comment: Yup, nice solution, also you can try to do it whithout local state, just only with Redux logic.

Answer (score 0):

**For Some Reason in next.js**

This gets called on render without a click event even happening

```
onClick={dispatch(logoutUser())}
```

and this works as expected on the click event

```
 onClick={()=> dispatch(logoutUser())}
```